# Model is trained to predict whether the spellings in the sentence is correct or not

Tags: html, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

When I try to run my code it shows me the warning

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 256) for input Tensor("embedding_input:0", shape=(None, 256), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1).

W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1744] OP_REQUIRES failed at cast_op.cc:124 : Unimplemented: Cast string to float is not supported
```

127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2020 20:51:50] "POST /submit HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Here is my function

```
def predict():
    input = [x for x in request.form.values()]
    prediction = model.predict(input)
    return render_template("index.html",prediction_text = 'Output is $ {}'.format(prediction))
```

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to say what went wrong without the complete code. As the warning message suggests, the model was trained on the input of the shape (None, 256) but while predicting you are using different input. Kindly feed the data to predict function which has the same features and dimension as the input data that is used to train the model.

I have provided an example below that imitates the error you are facing. Here I have trained the model on 8 columns but during predict I have used just 1 column.

**Code -**

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
# MLP for Pima Indians Dataset saved to single file
import numpy as np
from numpy import loadtxt
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Concatenate

# load pima indians dataset
dataset = np.loadtxt("/content/pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]

input1 = Input(shape=(8,))

# define model
x1 = Dense(12, input_shape = (2,), activation='relu')(input1)
x = Dense(8, activation='relu')(x1)
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(inputs=input1, outputs=x)

# compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Model Summary
model.summary()

# Fit the model
model.fit(x=X, y=Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)

# evaluate the model
scores = model.predict(dataset[:,0])
```

**Output-**

```
1.15.2
Model: "model_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, 8)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 12)                108       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 8)                 104       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 9         
=================================================================
Total params: 221
Trainable params: 221
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-32d25cb68448> in <module>()
     42 
     43 # evaluate the model
---> 44 scores = model.predict(dataset[:,0])

3 frames
/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    570                              ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
    571                              str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 572                              str(data_shape))
    573   return data
    574 

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_3 to have shape (8,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Comment: Our last tier has a duplicated 'x' and therefore you never reach it.